# Ссылка во фрейме открывает весь сайт

Tags: iframe

Добрый день.
Ситуация следующая - на странице сайта во фрейме выводится другой сайт, на котором есть форма с данными. При отправке формы выводимый во фрейме сайт открывается в полноэранном режиме. Что необходимо, что-бы результат продолжал открываться во фрейме?

Comment: Что ты используешь в качестве `backend`'а то е. серверного кода? Впрочем не думаю что это как-то поможет, я думаю тебе нужно направить результат во фрейм, связать данный iframe с сервером, и возвращать туда же результат) ты наверное его возвращаешь в адресную строку наверху) а не самого фрейма)

Comment: Проверьте значение атрибута `target` у `form`. https://webref.ru/html/form/target

Comment: Это оно! Проблем был именно в значении атрибута target. Большое спасибо за оперативную помощь, sorry за дубляж...